# Question on my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I am configuring a new unix box running MySQL8 on a CentOS7. This box is a dedicated Database server on a hyperV set-up with 16 CPU's 64 Gb of ram, 2Tb of SSD space. My configuration file is as per below. The server is mainly used for production OLAP processing. My question is:

1. Any glaring issues in the my.cnf config file?
2. Sysbench performance with O_DIRECT is quite inferior as compared to MySQL8 default of fsync on my server (as oppose to what I keep reading on this forum). Is this CentOS7 specific issue? Have anyone else encountered similar performance degradation during benchmarking?
  3.

-- My.Cnf --

```
[client]
#########Connect to 3306
port=3306
socket=/mysqldata/mysql-logs/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
#########User mysql as user
port=3306
user=mysql
basedir=/mysqldata/mysql
datadir=/mysqldata/mysql/innodb/
log_error=/mysqldata/mysql-logs/mysql.err
general_log_file=/mysqldata/mysql-logs/mysql.general.log
socket=/mysqldata/mysql-logs/mysql.sock

#########General
max_connections=200
table_open_cache=4000
table_open_cache_instances=16
back_log=50
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
character_set_server=latin1
skip-character-set-client-handshake
skip_log_bin=1
performance_schema=OFF
lc_messages_dir = /opt/mysql/share
lc_messages = en_US

######### Temporary table
tmp_table_size = 2000M
max_heap_table_size = 2000M

######### Slow Query
slow_query_log  = 1
slow_query_log_file=/mysqldata/mysql-logs/mysql-slow-query.log
long_query_time = 30

######### Files
innodb_log_group_home_dir=/mysqldata/innodb-logs/
innodb_log_file_size=2048M
innodb_log_files_in_group=5
innodb_open_files=4000

######### Innodb Buffer
innodb_buffer_pool_size=40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=16
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M

######### Tune
#########Happy to risk 1 sec of data loss for improved performance

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

######### These two lines below for max dirty page are server defauls from 8.0.3
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=90
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm=10



#########innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT_NO_FSYNC
#########innodb_checksum_algorithm=none

innodb_io_capacity=10000
innodb_io_capacity_max=40000
innodb_page_cleaners=16
innodb_undo_log_truncate=off

######### perf special
innodb_adaptive_flushing=1
innodb_flush_neighbors=0
innodb_read_io_threads=16
innodb_write_io_threads=16
innodb_purge_threads=4
innodb_adaptive_hash_index=0

######### monitoring
innodb_monitor_enable='%'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep these under 1% of RAM; else it might lead to swapping, which is bad:

```
tmp_table_size = 2000M
max_heap_table_size = 2000M
```

The others look reasonable.  Can't predict if anything else will need changing until you have run for some time.

Was that your sysbench test that decided on fsync?  O_DIRECT has been the common thinking for many years.

Will you be building and maintaining Summary Tables for OLAP?  That is often the most important performance issue in Data Warehousing.  Tweaking settings can help by a few percent; Summarizing can give you 10-fold.

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
24 hours or more of UPTME is important, if you can get there.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
top for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
for server tuning analysis.